# Symfony external library - Payone

Tags: symfony, payone

Has anybody ever used Symfony in conjunction with payone(payone.de)?

I got the SDK and it has the folders js, locale and php.

My problem: I don't really know how to include/use them in my project(inexperienced in Symfony) because I don't know where I should place it and how to include it. I read about the auto loader but since the SDK doesn't follow the standards needed(concerning folder structure) I guess it's not the way to go.

Comment: if the classes are following the PEAR-style non-namespaced convention, you can use psr-0 autoloading too. See my edited answer.

Comment: Do you use really payone.com or the SDK from payone.de it sound a bit like the payone.de SDK.

Comment: Well, I just looked it up and it's actually the one from payone.de - sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can autoload all classes with the `psr-0` too if the classes are following the PEAR-style non-namespaced convention.

To manage the vendor download via composer, you can define a package in your `composer.json` directly.

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "payone/php-sdk",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://github.com/PAYONE/PHP-SDK/archive/master.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "psr-0": { "Payone_": "php/" }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "payone/php-sdk": "1.0.*"
    }
}
```

**Note:** This repository type has a few limitations and should be avoided whenever possible:

- Composer will not update the package unless you change the `version` field.

Comment: The Payone SDK is hosted on GitHub: http://github.com/PAYONE/PHP-SDK/archive/master.zip

https://github.com/PAYONE/PHP-SDK

Comment: Yes, the are following the PEAR convention, so you can use psr-0 autoloading. Use the posted zipball above as dist url.

Comment: But wait, are you sure, the posted sdk from payone.**de** is the same for payone.**com**?

Comment: This is for the german Payone payment service (payone.de) but the folder description on top "I got the SDK and it has the folders js, locale and php." sounds a bit like the SDK above.

Comment: Hmm, maybe they are using the same API ^^